# PostgreSQL doesn't insert values into table?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I'm working on a PHP code that runs a query on my PostgreSQL database:

```
$insert = pg_query($pg_conn, 
"INSERT INTO kullanicilar(id, u_name, u_firstname, u_lastname, register_date, gold, exp, play_times, level)
VALUES($k_id, '$u_name', '$u_firstname', '$u_lastname', 'NOW()', 0, 0, 0, 1);"
);

if ($insert) {
    echo 'Insert succeeded.';
} else {
    echo 'An error occurs when inserting';
}
```

I'm getting **An error occurs when inserting** message every time. What's wrong with my code?

**-Edit- (Details)**

I'm using Heroku Postgres. My variables' definitions are like this;

```
$k_id = intval($basic['id']); //int
$u_name = $basic['name']; //string
$u_firstname = $basic['first_name']; //string
$u_lastname = $basic['last_name']; //string
```

Here is a part of my heroku log:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_pconnect(): Unable to connect to Postg
reSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server r
unning on host "-----.amazonaws.com" and accepting\n\tTCP/
IP connections on port 5432? in /app/www/index.php on line 91, referer: http://a
pps.facebook.com/---/

PHP Warning:  pg_last_error() expects parameter 1 to be
resource, boolean given in /app/www/index.php on line 119, referer: http://apps
.facebook.com/---/

PHP Warning:  pg_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be r
esource, null given in /app/www/index.php on line 106, referer: http://apps.face
book.com/---/

PHP Warning:  pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be reso
urce, boolean given in /app/www/index.php on line 107, referer: http://apps.face
book.com/---/

PHP Warning:  pg_last_error(): No PostgreSQL link opene
d yet in /app/www/index.php on line 111, referer: http://apps.facebook.com/---/

PHP Warning:  pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be reso
urce, boolean given in /app/www/index.php on line 98, referer: http://apps.faceb
ook.com/---/
```

Comment: Use pg_query_params() to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I found this http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php, but I don't know what should I add as a third parameter **params**. In other say, I don't know **x** in `pg_query_params ($pg_conn, $myquery , x )`. Thanks.

Comment: And what ***is*** the error?

Comment: *could not connect to server* that's your problem. It doesn't even connect, how should it insert anything then?

Comment: Yes, that's true. It was a connect problem. And solved by telling **port=5482** and **sslmode=require** to pg_pconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `register_date` is supposed to be a `timestamp` (with time zone), it should be `now()` (without single quotes, a function call) instead of `'now()'` (with single quotes, a string literal).

Postgres issues a more detailed error message. Check the DB logs.

`pgAdmin` is just a GUI. If it resides on a client it may not have access top the log files on the server at all. If it resides on the same machine, it just needs to be configured properly.

Every halfway decently configured Postgres server writes log files. Look in [`postgresql.conf` at the settings described here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHERE) to find out or configure where.

Comment: Erwin Brandstetter, still not working. I removed quotes of now() but the same error stands.

Comment: @MehmetEminAcar: Without more info the rest is just a guessing game. Follow Frank's link or look at the DB logs for a more detailed error message.

Comment: I used **echo pg_last_error();** and it doesn't give me an error. I'm using pgAdmin 3. When I looking at Server Status' log section, it says "Logs are not available for this server".

Comment: @MehmetEminAcar: I added a paragraph about log files to my answer.